# Use input() and print() at the same time (like in a chat)

Tags: python, printing, input, terminal

I am learning Python, and I have decided to make some practise by coding a mini chat in terminal, with a server and a client.
But there is a problem, to make a real chat, the client must be able to type, send and receive messages in the same time like that:

```
//MESSAGES
>bla bla to send
```

So messages are scrolling while in the bottom of the shell, there's my input.

I have searched the web how to make that, maybe the multi-threading, no. The input() fonction blocks the process.

If you have an answer to my question, it'll be great!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This response might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697305/python-command-line-input-in-a-process

Answer (score 1):

On Unix systems, you might want to check out [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29), which is a library designed to do this type of thing. Python has [a module for it](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/curses.html#module-curses) in the standard library.

There is a good tutorial on using curses in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/curses.html). This also suggests [the console module](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm) for Windows users.

Comment: Okay, I'll check that. Thank you! EDIT: Is there a Windows version of Curses ?

Comment: I founds this which works when importating: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/