# Python MySqlchat refresh console automatically

Tags: python, mysql, console, chat

When I search for Python and Chat I always read TCP/ IP.
They use Sockets to update the Console with new incoming data. But I don't find a way to refresh the console when I use an online MySql database with password etc..

Example:

I want to have a simple Console Chat, where you can write with somebody, and the incoming Text refreshes automatically when somebody writes something.

Or with Threads:

When I load the Text (like in a chat) from the Database and print it out it always prints the text again and again.

Comment: Why should the database make any difference to how to refresh the screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use input() and print() at the same time (like in a chat)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010446/use-input-and-print-at-the-same-time-like-in-a-chat)

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010446/use-input-and-print-at-the-same-time-like-in-a-chat
You need 2 threads, one for sending and one for receiving.

Comment: 2 Threads. And then i can read from the database permanenttly with a While loop or do you have a little example for me, that would be soooo cool :D