# input() is blocking the use of processes

Tags: python, multithreading, input, serial-port, multiprocessing

I have a problem with multiprocessing. If I am waiting for input in a thread the process is not starting.

The class to put the input into a queue in the background:

```
class InputCatcher(Thread):
    def __init__(self, input_queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.input_queue = input_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.input_queue.put(input()) # <<-- Without this it works!
```

The class that will not start:

```
class Usb(Process):
    def __init__(self, port, ctrl=Controller()):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.usb_port = port
        self.ctrl = ctrl


    def run(self):
        self.ctrl.usb_ports.append(self.usb_port)
        ser = Serial(self.usb_port, 115200)
        while True:
            dsl = ser.readline()
            self.ctrl.get_dataset_queue().put(['USBDS', dsl])
            print(dsl)
```

Starting with:

```
ic = InputCatcher(self.input_queue)
ic.setDaemon(True)
ic.start()

usbs = []
for port in usb_ports():
    if not port in ctrl.xbee_ports:
        usbs.append(Usb(port, ctrl))

for usb in usbs:
    usb.daemon = True
    usb.start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `input`, it is blocking the entire Python process, not just the thread it runs in. This happens because reading from STDIN, like reading from any other file-like object, involves making a blocking syscall - that is, `input` blocking to wait for user input happens at the OS level, rather than inside Python's own thread management code. Python threads are essentially invisible to the OS process scheduler, so *Python itself* gets blocked.

The usual way around blocking problems like this is to use processes instead of threads. If you make InputCatcher into a process rather than a thread, then it becomes a separate OS-level process that the OS can schedule independently, and so the syscall will only block *that* process and not the main one.

---

*Except*, that Python automatically [closes STDIN when you spawn a process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5697326/779200).

So, you would need to have the producer for the queue in the main process, and only the consumer in another one. This is also a trivial adaption - don't start the producer (InputCatcher) running until *after* all of the consumer processes have spawned. That involves moving the line:

```
ic.start()
```

to below the two loops. But in this case, there's no need for that to be backgrounded at all - it doesn't run simultaneously with other things. So, you can forget about the InputCatcher class entirely, and just write your code like this:

```
for usb in usbs:
    usb.daemon = True
    usb.start()

while True:
    input_queue.put(input())
```

You might also want to consider a particular input - say, the empty string - to end the program. Having the input in the main run makes this really easy by just ending the loop:

```
while True:
    data = input('Type data; or enter to exit: ')
    if not data:
        break
    input_queue.put(data)
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply,
now i have another problem, i wrote a test for it:

[link](http://pastebin.com/2xy1X6ck)

Comment: @Tweek I see you've already asked another question and accepted the answer, but I've updated my answer here to include how to get around that problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
self.input_queue.put(input())
```

This means: ask a user for input *right now*, than put whatever user input was ino a queue.

Looks like that should be something like

```
self.input_queue.put(lambda: input())
```

Looks like you have omitted some plumbing from your code, so it can't be run as is.

Comment: Ok, promising start, could downwoter please explain what's wrong with te answer so I could improve it? :)