# Python EOFError with raw_input() when calling Process.start()

Tags: python, linux, exception, multiprocessing

I am writing a 2-process program to echo a line of raw input while heartbeat once every second.

Here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def echo():
    while True:
        a = raw_input('type something')
        print 'you typed: ', a

def ticking():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=echo, args=())
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=ticking, args=())
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

When I run this script, there is always an EOFError thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "t.py", line 7, in echo
a = raw_input('type something')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

What is wrong here? How to correct this?

Comment: You can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5697326/6021610 Hope it can help you :)

Comment: @SamJia thx! It helped.

Comment: @kvorobiev Yup Thank you.