# input() function breaks Process invocation in Python with multiprocessing module

Tags: python, pycharm, multiprocessing

I wrote this simple code in Python 3.11 to learn the multiprocessing module:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def proc(text):
    while True:
        print(text)
        time.sleep(1)

print(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=proc, args=('hi',))
    p.start()

    input('Press any key to exit')
    p.terminate()
```

The idea is for process *p* to keep printing a text until the main process calls *p.terminate()*.

But when I run this code, here's what I get:

[image: print1]

The process *p* is never called. But if I remove the line with the input() function, the program runs as expected:

[image: print2]

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?
I'm running this code inside PyCharm IDE in Windows 10.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Mac. I get what you expected. How exactly are your running this? It looks like you have VSCode. Why is `__main__` and `__mp_main__` being printed??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I should have added that info: I'm running this inside PyCharm in Windows 10. And I'm printing  ``__name__`` to check if the process p is being called, since multiprocessing "runs" the file twice

Comment: Ok, but what does "run inside PyCharm" mean precisely? Please try to give us outputs that are consistent with your example, to avoid unnecessary confusion. To rule out it being a PyCharm issue, can you try just running outside of Pycharm, e.g. just from the console?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga PyCharm is an IDE just like VSCode, and it has a play button to execute the active file. That was what I meant by "run inside PyCharm", sorry for not explaining well. And guess what? I tried running the .py file in the terminal and works just fine. I really don't understand why this is happening exclusively in the IDE. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, the "play button" in an IDE may involve *all sorts of things* to actually execute your file, which could potentially interfere with the `multiprocessing.Process`. This is why I ask. Even when I use PyCharm, atlhough I'm mostly on VSCode nowadays, I still just run the code from the terminal in PyCharm manually.

Comment: Are you entering any data? It seems as though `input` is returning right away ... or perhaps some exception is raised but displayed in a different window perhaps? You could `print(repr(input('Press any key to exit')))` and even wrap in it a try/except that prints the exception.

Comment: And just a quick note, multiprocessing on windows has to run as new instance of python and import the needed modules. It calls it `__mp_main__` to distinguish it from the parent `__main__`.

Comment: Hi @tdelaney! I tried to wrap the ``input('Press any key to exit')`` call inside the try/except as you suggested but the program didn't  throw any exceptions. Also, I checked, and the ``input`` function is not returning righ away. It seems to be a problem in PyCharm's execution script or something like that. Even in online Python interpreters this code is working like expected.

Comment: @HenriqueRodrigues - thanks for the update. As juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, IDE's can be tricky with code execution. It does leave me puzzled, though.

Comment: Note that it's not that "IDEs can be tricky with code execution" - that's nonsense. The IDE does not run your code, Python does and the IDE connects as a debugger. What is tricky are applications that rely on a terminal behaving a specific way. Just like Command Prompt's old Windows Console Host and the new Windows Terminal behave differently, so do the terminals built into IDE's. They have their own behaviour which may differ from the terminals you'd expect your code to run in normally. The use of the `input()` function causes interaction with whatever terminal the program runs in.

Answer (score 0):

Any application that writes data to the standard out or standard error stream, or that takes data from the standard in stream, interacts with the terminal it is executing on.

Although that may sound complicated, it simply means that if your script uses `print()` or `input()`, how it behaves exactly from the point of view of the user will depend on the terminal the user is running it in. The terminal has to do the actual displaying of what is printed and it does the actual job of collecting user input. (Note that this gets more complicated if you use libraries that directly interact with system APIs reading keyboard input, like `keyboard`)

This terminal can be the Windows Console Host (the default for Command Prompt in early Windows 10 and before), the Windows Terminal (the default for PowerShell in Windows 11), but also a terminal emulator running your script on the cloud over SSH (running in some terminal emulation mode) for example, or whatever terminal your Linux distribution implements.

When you execute your script from an IDE, it can implement its own terminal that may work slightly differently from the terminal you're used to on your operating system. PyCharm is a good example. Its terminal behaves differently from both the Windows Terminal and the Windows Console Host, even though you may be running it on Windows.

A script that uses both terminal input and output and `multiprocessing` can cause additional confusion, if you're relying on the terminal responding in some timely fashion. Your script runs as expected on Windows Console Host and Windows Terminal, but doesn't on PyCharm's terminal.

In PyCharm, you can easily see this difference by running your script directly from the IDE with some run configuration. And then running it again from the 'Terminal' prompt with something like `python myscript.py`. You'll find that the behaviour in a system terminal is fine.

(Unrelated note: your input prompt says to press "any key", but `input()` will only terminate your script if someone presses Enter/Return, since that completes the collection of input by `input()`)

You can't really 'fix' this, since there's nothing to fix - everything is working as it should. However, if the `input()` statement is only there for debugging purposes, a solution would be to use a library (like `keyboard`) that waits for user input without relying on the running Terminal. Install it with `pip install keyboard` or using the Project Settings in the UI, and then try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
from keyboard import read_key


def proc(text):
    while True:
        print(text)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=proc, args=('hi',))
    p.start()

    print("Press any key to stop the process...")
    read_key()
    p.terminate()
```

Note that this actually stops when you press any key, and works the same in all terminals.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick research I've found out what was the cause of the issue. The **multiprocess.Process()** has the functionality of the **threading.Thread()** library. This means that when you initiate the **Process()** object by using the **target** parameter in its initiator and passing a function/method, the **Process()** object will behave like a **Thread()** object.

[image: Screenshot of python docs 1]

Because of this, if you call **p.terminate()** you will kill the thread immediately after initiating it. Even if you remove **p.terminate()**, there is still another issue, even if **Process()** will have the functionality of a thread in this scenario, when you call **p.start()**, the process class is immediately shutting down the **STDIN** stream, thus not allowing you to use the **input()** method.
[image: Screenshot of python docs 2]

https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5697326/16587692